# Scheme explanation(construct)

Tags: scheme, element, cons

Can someone please explain me why :

```
(define a (lambda() (cons a #f)))

(car (a)) ==> procedure

((car (a))) ==> (procedure . #f)
```

I don't think I get it. Thanks

Comment: I believe it becomes a little bit clearer if you look at the value of `(a)` and compare that with `((car (a)))`.

Comment: I don't understand the (car (a)).It's the same to(car (a) '()) ??

Comment: No, that would be nonsense. `car` takes one parameter, not two.

Comment: You'true ,but "car" choose from a "cons"...or not? (car(cons 1 2)). In my example i have (car(a)). This is what i can't understand.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you don't understand. What do you expect `(car (a))` and `((car (a)))` to be? (In `(car (a))`, `(a)` is not the list `(cons a '())` - or `(list a)` - it is a procedure call.)

Comment: I checked it again and now i uderstand. Thanks.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu if you understand now, you should check the one answer that was most helpful to you. This will also give you a +2 rep bump.  And with 15 rep you can also *upvote* any answer that you deem useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
(define a (lambda() (cons a #f)))
```

defines a procedure, `a`, which when called will return the pair

```
(<the procedure a> . #f)
```

i.e. whose `car` is the procedure itself, and whose `cdr` is `#f`.

In other words, the result of evaluating

```
(a)
```

is the result of *calling* the procedure `a` with no arguments, which is, by definition of `a` above,

```
(<the procedure a> . #f)
```

Hence,

```
(car (a))
```

is `<the procedure a>` (because it means "call `car` with the result of evaluating `(a)`")

When you add another pair of parentheses

```
((car (a)))
```

you're calling that procedure, which - since it's the procedure `a` - returns the same result as `(a)`,

```
 (<the procedure a> . #f)
```

Answer (score 1):

`define` from top level defines a global variable `a`.

The anonymous procedure `(lambda() (cons a #f)`, when called,  makes a pair out of the evaluation of `a` and `#f`.

When you evaluate `a` you get a procedure. In my system you get `#<procedure:a>`.

When you evaluate `(a)` you get `(#<procedure:a> . #f)`. Now the way procedures display is highly implementation dependent. There are no standard, but many will use a convension where the name `a` would be present, but don't count on it.

Since `a` also can be accessed as the `car` of the result of calling `a` you can `((car (a)))` and get the same as `(a)`. That's because `(eq? a (car (a)))` is `#t`.